# Strip tags, but replace block elements with space

Tags: php, html

Let's asume i got the floowing html code:

```
<h1>Hello</h1><p>world</p>
```

ifi use strip_tags on this string the result is `helloworld`. I'd want it to be `hello world`.

But also, if i have something like this:

```
hello <strong>w</strong>orld
```

i want the result to be `hello world` not `hello w orld`

So just like the title says: is there a reliable way to replace all block html elements with a space and strip the inline elements?

Comment: Please post the code that you used to attempt to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tried something, before asking for help in SO.

```
<?php

function removeElements($text) {
    $text = preg_replace('/<(h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|p|div)[^>]*>/', ' ', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/<\/(h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|p|div)>/', ' ', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $text);
    $text = stipElements($text);
    return $text;
}

function stipElements($text) {
    $text = preg_replace('/<[^>]+>/', '', $text);
    return $text;
}

$text = '<h1>Hello</h1><p>world</p>';
$text = removeElements($text);
echo $text;

$text = 'hello <strong>w</strong>orld';
$text = removeElements($text);
echo $text;
```

Output:

```
Hello world hello world
```